# Using the React useState hook update function inside a Async function

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Trying to setState does not seem to update the state immediately and I'm not sure how to achieve the desired result.

```
  const Settings = (props: Props) => {
      const { user } = props;
      const initState: State = {
        newName: user.displayName,
        newAvatarUrl: user.avatarUrl,
        disabled: false,
      };
      const [form, setForm] = useState(initState);

  const handleUploadFile = async () => {
    const fileElement = document.getElementById('upload-file') as HTMLFormElement;
    const file = fileElement.files[0];

    if (file == null) {
      return;
    }
    setForm({ ...form, disabled: true });

    try {
      const response = await asynFunc1()

      await asyncFun2(response)

      setForm({ ...form, newAvatarUrl: response.url });

      await asyncFunc3(form.newAvatarUrl) // Expected: response.url Observed: old value
    } catch (error) {
      consol.log(error)
    } finally {
      setForm({ ...form, disabled: false });
    }
  };

  return (
        <h4>Your Avatar</h4>
        <Avatar
          src={form.newAvatarUrl}
          style={{
            display: 'inline-flex',
            verticalAlign: 'middle',
            marginRight: 20,
            width: 60,
            height: 60,
          }}
        />
        <label htmlFor="upload-file">
          <Button variant="outlined" color="primary" component="span" disabled={form.disabled}>
            Update Avatar
          </Button>
        </label>
        <input
          accept="image/*"
          name="upload-file"
          id="upload-file"
          type="file"
          style={{ display: 'none' }}
          onChange={handleUploadFile}
        />
  );
};
```

It looks like setForm is not synchronous but it does not return a promise so I'm not sure how to use it in a synchronous fashion.

Comment: state is updated asynchronously. You can't log the updated state immediately after calling the function to update the state. Component will have to re-render in order for it to see the updated state. You can use `useeffect` hook to execute any code after the state is updated.

Comment: @Yousaf Thanks. I changed the function call to use the value I needed and not depend on the state. The view still does not reflect the updated state which means the state wasn't actually updated right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment the state update is async. Instead you should just pass response.url to the asyncFunc3 call and set your form state after that successfully returns. Would be something like this:

```js
const Settings = (props: Props) => {
  const { user } = props;
  const initState: State = {
    newName: user.displayName,
    newAvatarUrl: user.avatarUrl,
    disabled: false,
  };
  const [form, setForm] = useState(initState);

  const handleUploadFile = async () => {
    const fileElement = document.getElementById('upload-file') as HTMLFormElement;
    const file = fileElement.files[0];

    if (file == null) {
      return;
    }
    setForm({ ...form, disabled: true });

    try {
      const response = await asynFunc1()

      await asyncFun2(response)

      await asyncFunc3(response.url)
      
      setForm({ ...form, newAvatarUrl: response.url });
    } catch (error) {
      consol.log(error)
    } finally {
      setForm({ ...form, disabled: false });
    }
  };

  return (
        <h4>Your Avatar</h4>
        <Avatar
          src={form.newAvatarUrl}
          style={{
            display: 'inline-flex',
            verticalAlign: 'middle',
            marginRight: 20,
            width: 60,
            height: 60,
          }}
        />
        <label htmlFor="upload-file">
          <Button variant="outlined" color="primary" component="span" disabled={form.disabled}>
            Update Avatar
          </Button>
        </label>
        <input
          accept="image/*"
          name="upload-file"
          id="upload-file"
          type="file"
          style={{ display: 'none' }}
          onChange={handleUploadFile}
        />
  );
};
```

Comment: Thanks, this is indeed what I had to do for the logic to be correct. The view still does not reflect the updated state.  I was under the impression that changing the state would trigger a re-render but I'm not sure how to programmatically trigger that.

Comment: Could be that the user prop is being updated as well, and the entire thing re-renders? Can't really tell without more info. Perhaps you could make a small example on https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-hr3hhj

Comment: Thanks Viktor. While typing out an example I realized it was the finally block that was over-writing the update. https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-byvglp Any idea how I can change the state similar to how finally works?

Comment: Yes, when you're destructuring the state object the way you're doing it there, you are destructuring your initial state (thus over-writing in a sort of race-condition). Try doing this instead `setState(prevState => ({ ...prevState, flag: false });` instead. By passing a function instead, you're taking the state "frame", and will not be using an outdated state-object

Comment: Amazing! Thanks Viktor.